# Print Telerik report more than one time in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, telerik-reporting

I used Telerik Report in my WPF application to print a receipt report:

```
    SalesReport _salesReport = new SalesReport(_netShiftSalesAmount);
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings printerSettings = new System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings();
    System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController standardPrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
    Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor reportProcessor = new Telerik.Reporting.Processing.ReportProcessor();
    reportProcessor.PrintController = standardPrintController;
    Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource instanceReportSource = new Telerik.Reporting.InstanceReportSource();
    instanceReportSource.ReportDocument = _salesReport;
    reportProcessor.PrintReport(instanceReportSource, printerSettings);
```

It's work, but I want to print more than on receipt in each payment,(let us say 3 receipt) each receipt contain different items.

How can I call the same report more than one time?

Thanks in advance

Comment: be aware that you're using WinForm objects in your WPF application.  `System.Drawing.Printing.PrintController - Controls how a document is printed, when printing from a Windows Forms application.`

Comment: And like any other object in C#, if you want to print things that have different content/items on it, then you need to probably create a new `SaleReport` for each receipt and a new `InstanceReportSource` for each receipt; then call the `reportProcessor.PrintReport` for each receipt as well.